# Scroll to pressed Character in a Listview

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Listview filled with a list of objects sorted in alphabetical order.

What I want is to press a key on the keyboard, E for example.
Then the Listview automatically scrolls to the objects starting with E.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is already implemented in `ListView`, you may have to look at this [TextSearch Class MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textsearch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get an idea of how to use it.

Comment: Thank you, didn't notice that :)